# Understand memory leak types in valgrind memcheck tool

Tags: c, memory-leaks, malloc, valgrind, free

I am using Valgrind tool to understand the different types of memory leaks:
Directly lost,Indirectly lost Still reachable and possibly lost.
Ex1:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
main() {
    int *p, i;
     p = malloc(10*sizeof(int));
      for(i = 0;i < 10;i++)
       p[i] = i;
       //free(p);
      printf("Freed\n ");

}

LEAK SUMMARY:
==31770==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==31770==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==31770==      possibly lost: 20 bytes in 1 blocks
==31770==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==31770==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks


eg2:
main() {
    int *p, i;
     p = malloc(10*sizeof(int));

//     printf("freed");
}

 LEAK SUMMARY:
==14950==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==14950==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==14950==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==14950==    still reachable: 40 bytes in 1 blocks
==14950==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks

If a uncomment the printf statement:
 LEAK SUMMARY:
==15889==    definitely lost: 40 bytes in 1 blocks
==15889==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==15889==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==15889==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==15889==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
```

Please explain me exactly about those different memory leaks.

Answer (score 2):

A quick internet search leads to the following site:

http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/faq.html#faq.deflost

> The details are in the Memcheck section of the user manual.
>
> In short:
>
> - "definitely lost" means your program is leaking memory -- fix
>   those leaks!
> - "indirectly lost" means your program is leaking memory in a
>   pointer-based structure. (E.g. if the root node of a binary tree is
>   "definitely lost", all the children will be "indirectly lost".) If you
>   fix the "definitely lost" leaks, the "indirectly lost" leaks should go
>   away.
> - "possibly lost" means your program is leaking memory, unless
>   you're doing unusual things with pointers that could cause them to
>   point into the middle of an allocated block; see the user manual for
>   some possible causes. Use --show-possibly-lost=no if you don't want to
>   see these reports.
> - "still reachable" means your program is probably ok -- it didn't
>   free some memory it could have. This is quite common and often
>   reasonable. Don't use --show-reachable=yes if you don't want to see
>   these reports.
> - "suppressed" means that a leak error has been suppressed. There
>   are some suppressions in the default suppression files. You can ignore
>   suppressed errors.

**Update:**

The difference between "definitely lost" and "still reachable" is as follows:
Your memory is *definitely lost* if all references to it are gone and you did not free it before - the classical case of a memory leak.
It is *still reachable* when, at the end of your program's lifetime, you did not free all memory that was dynamically allocated **but** there are still valid references to it, so that it *could have been freed*.

Since all of the program's memory is freed at program termination anyway, this isn't usually a problem. However for a long running program and large memory allocations, it might be worth manually freeing those if you don't need them anymore.

Let me show you a simple example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char *still_reachable;
char *definitely_lost_global;

int main()
{
    char *definitely_lost_local;

    // allocate 10 bytes of memory -> will get lost
    definitely_lost_local = malloc(10 * sizeof *definitely_lost_local);
    // allocate 20 bytes of memory -> will get lost
    definitely_lost_global = malloc(20 * sizeof *definitely_lost_global);

    definitely_lost_global = NULL;
    // Now there aren't any references to those 20 bytes anymore, so memory is lost.

    // allocate 40 bytes of memory. The global pointer has static storage duration.
    // We do not change the pointer, so the respective memory will
    // be still reachable by the end of program lifetime
    still_reachable = malloc(40 * sizeof *still_reachable);
} // scope of definitely_lost_local ends here --> 10 bytes are lost!
```

We can guess that 10+20 = 30 bytes will be lost in this example, while 40 bytes will be still reachable. So let's check with valgrind:

```
==19474== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==19474== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==19474== Using Valgrind-3.13.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==19474== Command: ./prog
==19474==
==19474==
==19474== HEAP SUMMARY:
==19474==     in use at exit: 70 bytes in 3 blocks
==19474==   total heap usage: 3 allocs, 0 frees, 70 bytes allocated
==19474==
==19474== LEAK SUMMARY:
==19474==    definitely lost: 30 bytes in 2 blocks
==19474==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==19474==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==19474==    still reachable: 40 bytes in 1 blocks
==19474==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==19474== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
==19474==
==19474== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==19474== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Voilá, as expected.

Comment: Thanks.But i am confused between definitely lost and still reachable.

Comment: thank you so much for explaining so clearly with the example.

Comment: :But i have one doubt.If i am adding "definitely_lost_local = NULL;" still it shows Definitely lost.Whats the difference if definitely_lost_local is made to NULL ?

Comment: main(){ int *ptr; ptr=malloc(5*sizeof(int));}-->showing possibly lost ,why not showing definetely lost?

Comment: The only difference of setting `definitely_lost_local = NULL;` somewhere in `main()` is that your only reference to that memory gets lost earlier (otherwise when leaving the function).

Comment: I've created a set of simple examples in [Simple examples to the different leak types reported by Valgrind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71413181/simple-examples-to-the-different-leak-types-reported-by-valgrind)